# incrementing and iterating inside list comprehension

Tags: python

```
x = ['a','b','c','y','h']
e = 'fork'
w = 'knife'
s = 'what %s is the %s  doing inside the %s'
t = [s%(x[0],e,w) for i in x]
print t
```

If I run the above code I get something like :

`'what a is the for doing inside the knife'` repeated the amount of times there are elements in x. What I want to do instead is iterate over x so that the output is something like :

```
'what a is the fork doing inside the knife','what b is the fork doing inside the knife'
'what c is the fork doing inside the knife','what y is the fork doing inside the knife',
'what h is the fork doing inside the knife'
```

How do I do this in an list comprehension? is it better to do this in a loop instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `t = [s%(x[0],e,w) for i in x]` with `t = [s%(i,e,w) for i in x]`; you are not iterating over `x`.